# What format (vectors, meshgrids, or otherwise) does SciPy's dblquad require for 2D integration?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have a function `myfunc_Cartesian` which was interpolated on a Cartesian grid using `RectBivariateSpline`, and now I need to integrate it in polar coordinates using SciPy's `dblquad`. I should be able to do this by defining an intermediate function which converts from polar to Cartesian, and then evaluates the interpolant.

Below I have a function which does the conversion for meshgrids of radial and angular coordinates `rr` and `theta`.

```
def myfunc_polar(rr, theta):
    # Transform polar to Cartesian
    xx = rr*np.cos(theta)
    yy = rr*np.sin(theta)
    # Evaluate the spline on these points
    return myfunc_Cartesian(xx, yy, grid=False)
```

However, I don't know how `dblquad` expects the function to take arguments. I did not see an answer to this when I checked the documentation. Should `myfunc_polar` be written so that it expects `rr` and `theta` to be meshgrids, or vectors spanning meshgrids, or something else? How can I write it in a way that `dblquad` will handle correctly?

EDIT: To be clear, I will do an integral like

```
myfunc = lambda theta, r: chi0_static_polar(r, theta)
dblquad(myfunc, rmin, rmax, thmin, thmax)
```

Following hpaulj's suggestion, when I put in a print statement for the two arguments, I get a stream of scalars, so `dblquad` operates on scalar arguments as hpaulj said.

Comment: It isn't clear how this function relates to the `func(y, x)` that `dblquad` will be calling repeatedly.  `y` and `x` are scalars, `x` range between the `a` and `b` floats, and `y` between `gfun(x)` and `hfun(x)`.  During debugging it may help to include `print` statements in the functions that show what the arguments are.

Comment: This function *is* the function that `dblquad` is meant to integrate. I will edit the question to reflect that. Your suggestion of printing `rr` and `theta` is a good one; I'll try that and add more information if it is elucidating or raises more questions.